# How to append a new value into ElasticSearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have an existing index like

`POST /test/login/1
{
  "build_version": "1.0.0",
  "login_history": {
    "timestamp": 1504608869
  }
}`

now, I want to append another timestamp into "login_history", like:

`{
  "build_version": "1.0.0",
  "login_history": {
    "timestamp": 1504608869,
    "timestamp": 1504610670
  }
}`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
POST /test/login/2
POST /test/login/3
POST /test/login/etc.
```

Comment: I will get an updated JSON file with lastest timestamp.